# perl script to get specific user data if not ask again?

Tags: perl

I need to receive either 5 or 10 or 15 or 20 from user, if not i should ask them again until they enter any of four numbers. Here is the code, but not doing the same. Point out the logical misunderstanding.

```
print "Enter either 5 or 10 or 15 or 20): ";
my $obfuscation_percentage = <STDIN>; 
chomp $obfuscation_percentage; 
if ($obfuscation_percentage ne 5 or 10 or 15 or 20 ){
print "Enter valid number: "; }
$obfuscation_percentage = <STDIN>; 
chomp $obfuscation_percentage;
```

Comment: Here is the final working code..print "Enter obfuscation percentage value (5 or 10 or 15 or 20): ";
my $obfuscation_percentage;
while ($obfuscation_percentage = <STDIN>) { 
if ($obfuscation_percentage == 5 || $obfuscation_percentage == 10 || $obfuscation_percentage == 15 || $obfuscation_percentage == 20 ){
last;}
else {
print "Enter valid obfuscation percentage: "; }
}
chomp $obfuscation_percentage;

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't repeat anything. Typically, a `while()` loop would be used. Second, you're using `ne`, which compares strings. What you'd want is `==` for numerical input. Third, your `if` statements won't work. You have to repeat the full comparison:

```
if ($x == 5 || $x == 10 || $x == 15) {...}
```

Here's an example with a loop, and using `grep()` for the comparison:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (1){
    print "Enter either 5 or 10 or 15 or 20): ";
    my $obfuscation_percentage = <STDIN>; 
    chomp $obfuscation_percentage; 

    my @valid = qw(5 10 15 20);

    if (grep {$obfuscation_percentage == $_} @valid){
        print 10 * $obfuscation_percentage ."\n";
        last;
    }
}

__END__
Enter either 5 or 10 or 15 or 20): 7
Enter either 5 or 10 or 15 or 20): 12
Enter either 5 or 10 or 15 or 20): 5
50
```

Answer (score 0):

A few problems.

First of all, you don't loop at any point, nor do you ever check the second read from STDIN.  Here's your code prettified.

```
print "Enter either 5 or 10 or 15 or 20): ";
my $obfuscation_percentage = <STDIN>; 
chomp $obfuscation_percentage; 
if ($obfuscation_percentage ne 5 or 10 or 15 or 20 ){
    print "Enter valid number: "; 
}
$obfuscation_percentage = <STDIN>; 
chomp $obfuscation_percentage;
```

So you would need some sort of loop to read from stdin.

Second issue is, from [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)

> Binary "or" returns the logical disjunction of the two surrounding expressions. It's equivalent to || except for the very low precedence. This makes it useful for control flow:

So it won't work the way you think it will, like a list check.  You'd need to check each number or do something else.

Also `ne` is a string comparison, but you have integers on the right side of the operator, though Perl is probably smart enough to understand that.